# Slow boot on 20.04 dual booted with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, dell

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed alongside Windows 10 on my Dell G3-3579 laptop. Ubuntu takes a very long time (around 2 minutes) to boot compared to around 10 seconds on Windows 10. I have tried 16.04, 18.04 and 19.10 as well, but there is not much difference in the boot time.

Specs:

- Dell G3-3579
- RAM: 4GB
- HDD: 1TB
- SSD: 128GB
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with 4GB memory

Output of `systemd-analyze blame`: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Hp392cbm8s/

Output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/zy47vqCvzW/

I have also attached the output of `systemd-analyze plot` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqV23.jpg).

**Edit 1**: Output of `dmesg`: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/w8Hn4tQFJ9/

**Edit 2**: Output of `systemd-analyze time`:

```
Startup finished in 6.724s (firmware) + 6.666s (loader) + 6.153s (kernel) + 47.634s (userspace) = 1min 7.178s 
graphical.target reached after 44.983s in userspace
```

Could someone please help me analyze/fix this issue of slow boot?

Comment: Can you add the output of `dmesg` just after start+login?

Comment: @SerafimDahl done.

Comment: The only thing that sticks out is the calls to rfkill at the end of dmesg. What does `systemd-analyze time` say?

Comment: @SerafimDahl added the output.